# Suma de los cuadrados de los primeros 100 números impares

Tags: c++

Necesito que se sumen los números impares a cuadrado, es decir que dentro del 0 a 100 los numeros impares se coloquen al cuadrado y se sumen. ¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
     int suma = 0;
     int nuevo = 1;
     int i;
     for(i = 0; i < 100; i++){
          suma =  suma + nuevo * nuevo;
          nuevo = nuevo + 2;
     }
     cout << "La suma de los primeros 100 números impares naturales es " << suma << " ";
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¡Vas muy bien! ¿Podrías ser más específico con el problema que presentas? Para verificar si un número es impar  te recomiendo `numero % 2==0 `, esto devuelve `true` si el número es par.

Comment: Si es decir del 0 al 100 verificar cuales números son impar, estos ponerlos al cuadrado e irlos sumando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int suma = 0;

for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
   if(i % 2 == 1)
   {
      suma = suma + (i * i);
   }
}

//Imprimo la suma obtenida
```

Se hace un **ciclo for** desde **1** hasta **100** y se pregunta si el número es impar, en caso de serlo se haya el cuadrado de este número y se adiciona al valor de la **variable suma**, posteriormente imprimes el valor de esta variable.

Comment: ¿Por qué Tú pones i%2 == 1 y el comentario de arriba es i%2 == 0 cuál es la diferencia?

Comment: Un número es par si el resto de su división con 2 es 0 y es impar si el resto de su division con 2 es 1,  el resto se halla mediante i%2,  a ti te hacen falta los impares por lo que i%2 debe ser 1, el comentario de arriba te lo explica con los pares

Comment: Muy bien, si es lo que estaba viendo de tu código, muchas gracias una duda más ¿Por qué % y no /?

Comment: Son operadores distintos / es la división y % es el resto de la división 4/2 es 2 y 4%2 = 0 lo cual quiere decir que esta división no deja resto, puedes comprobarlo manualmente, divide tu mismo dos números cualquiera para que veas

Answer (score 2):

Si tienes en cuenta que los números impares pueden ser escritos de la forma 2n+1 puedes ahorrarte tiempo de procesamiento evitando verificar si el numero es impar, reducirías tus recorridos por el ciclo a la mitad.

```
int suma = 0;

for(int i = 1; i<=100; i+=2){
    suma = suma + (i*i);
}
// Imprimir el resultado de la suma
```

En este tipo de problemas el tiempo de procesamiento es despreciable pero cuando avances este tipo de cosas puede hacer la diferencia entre que tu programa se demore 1 minuto y no un siglo.

Comment: Hola, te doy mi voto positivo